# +[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat] substitute reserved words

Tags: nspredicate, stringwithformat, predicatewithformat

Is it possible to substitute reserved words, specifically `OR` and `AND`, into a `predicateFormat`?

I tried:

```
NSString *andOr = (isAnd ? @"AND" : @"OR");  // isAnd is a BOOL variable
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                          @"firstName == %@ %K lastName == %@",
                          user.firstName, andOr, user.lastName];
```

But I got:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "firstName == %@ %K lastName == %@"
```

I tried `%s` (and also `%S`) instead of `%K` but got the same exception.

My working solution for now is to create the `predicateFormat` separately.

```
NSString *predicateFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                             @"firstName == %%@ %@ lastName == %%@", andOr]; 
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateFormat,
                          user.firstName, user.lastName];
```

But, I was wondering if this could be done without creating `predicateFormat` separately.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, it can:

```
NSPredicate *firstName = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName == %@", [user firstName]];
NSPredicate *lastName = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lastName == %@", [user lastName]];
NSArray *subpredicates = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstName, lastName, nil];

NSPredicate *predicate = nil;
if (isAnd) {
  predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:subpredicates];
} else {
  predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:subpredicates];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using search bar text i am filtering the data.

Below code is simple and no need of any explanation

NSString *predFormat=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"FirstName CONTAINS[c] '%@' OR LastName CONTAINS[c] '%@' OR Phone CONTAINS[c] '%@'",searchValue,searchValue,searchValue]; //LIKE

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predFormat];

NSArray *tempData = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

Hope this will work for you..
Happy coding....